# Stored Procedure is not appearing in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, iis-6, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio 2008, I created a Stored Procedure, but its not appearing in the 'Stored Procedures' list when viewing in Object Explorer.

I've also restarted the server, and restarted my machine, and tested on other machines, and the Stored Procedure still isn't appearing.

I know that this Stored Procedure exists in the system because if I execute the following query:

```
exec dbo.sp_Orders
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure sp_Orders, Line 0
Procedure or Function 'sp_Orders' expects parameter '@OrderID', which was not supplied.
```

Therefore its recognising that the Stored Procedure exists, and even returns an error about a Parameter which was not supplied.

Why is this happening and how can I access the sproc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try followign to access your sp:

`exec sp_helptext xxxx` where xxxx is your sp name.

Comment: I tried `exec sp_helptext sp_Orders`, but I get the error: `The object 'sp_Orders' does not exist in database 'databaseA' or is invalid for this operation.`

Comment: I see, it may happen sometime that you created that sp in different database, try executing it with master database and any other db that you have in your server. I know it's silly but I myself did that couple of times

Comment: Hmm this doesnt seem to make sense to me as I had the correct database selected in the connection dropdown in SSMS (which I believe acts like `USE [databasename]`). I'm going to check through the databases anyway, but I doubt I'll have much luck :/

Comment: Had a look through the databases, it didn't make sense for the Stored Procedure to be in another database, but it does make sense that it could be in the `master` database, which is where i found it! Cheers!